# Change Divider Color OR theme of Android DatePicker Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, datepicker

I am tying to change the divider color of the `DatePicker` Dialog.

I already checked all duplicate questions but i didn't get anything which is working.

I want to use orange color instead of this blue color of this divider.

Right now my `datepicker` looks like this and i also want to remove this background of whole date picker.

I used this code for `datepicker` dialog

```
final Calendar calendarDate = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                            int dayOfMonth) {
            calendarDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendarDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendarDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        }
};
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext,
        dateSetListener, calendarDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarDate
                .get(Calendar.MONTH), calendarDate
                .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Screeshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Style to change the divider color/theme from your drawable image as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <style name="YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/dialog_divider_color</item>
     </style>
   </resources>
```

and update the `AndroidManifest.xml` file with the `android:theme="YourTheme"` for the `<activity/>`

Comment: For this i have to create image looks like divider? or i can use orange color directly?

Comment: You can use either image/color using above code. For image, Place the image in `drawable` folder and place `<item name="android:divider">@drawable/your_image_name</item>`. For Color, place `<item name="android:divider">@color/your_color</item>` in the above code.

Comment: I have to use Compulsary `parent="@android:style/Theme"` ? because in my case its `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"`as i need this type of theme

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But its not working. I am checking in android 4.2 google nexus 4 phone

Comment: @Sam_k In-detail analysis here: [Android: how to change the color of the datepicker divider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider).