# How to change TimePicker lines color in Appcompat theme?

Tags: android, styling, timepicker, android-appcompat

How to change TimePicker lines color between choosed number in Appcompat theme? The lines are blue, but i need orange lines.

I use TimePickerDialog with ContextThemeWrapper.

```
   TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(
        new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.timePicker), 
    this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

and style

```
<style name="timePicker">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/cab_background_top_play</item>
</style>
```

but the line have other id maybe. I'm not sure to use drawable or color only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use this answer to do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/20291416/2771869

Answer (score 7):

I solved this with own Timepicker class which extends android Timepicker class. I inspired by post [stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider/20291416#20291416](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider/20291416#20291416) which posted [mohammad rababah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2771869/mohammad-rababah) in comment below my ask.

Here is styled timepicker class:

```
public class StyledTimePicker extends TimePicker {

        public StyledTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            Class<?> internalRID = null;
            try {
                internalRID = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Field month = null;
            try {
                month = internalRID.getField("hour");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            NumberPicker npMonth = null;
            try {
                npMonth = (NumberPicker) findViewById(month.getInt(null));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Field day = null;
            try {
                day = internalRID.getField("minute");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            NumberPicker npDay = null;
            try {
                npDay = (NumberPicker) findViewById(day.getInt(null));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Field year = null;
            try {
                year = internalRID.getField("amPm");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            NumberPicker npYear = null;
            try {
                npYear = (NumberPicker) findViewById(year.getInt(null));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Class<?> numberPickerClass = null;
            try {
                numberPickerClass = Class.forName("android.widget.NumberPicker");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Field selectionDivider = null;
            try {
                selectionDivider = numberPickerClass.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                selectionDivider.setAccessible(true);
                selectionDivider.set(npMonth, getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.color.apptheme_color));
                selectionDivider.set(npDay, getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.color.apptheme_color));
                selectionDivider.set(npYear, getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.color.apptheme_color));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

You can change color apptheme_color only.

Thanks to [mohammad rababah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2771869/mohammad-rababah)

Comment: Where and how would you call this class?

Comment: You can add this class to XML layout. for example <com.yourpackage.views.StyledTimePicker ... />

Comment: @Navio53 could you share which library you use?

Comment: I used the timepicker library and the numberpicker library. Here is the link to the timepicker library which has a link to the numberpicker library: https://github.com/SimonVT/android-timepicker

Comment: Dont' know why this isn't marked as the right answer, this worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: hi, I realize it's been a while but has anyone figured out how to make the dividers connected? as in one long line from day to year?

Answer (score 0):

Expand res folder in your application and expand values folder. Then create themes.xml file on values folder. then replace all code in themes.xml file with below code.

```
<style name="MYTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">

   <item name="android:divider">@drawable/dialog_divider</item>

</style>
```

Then open your AndroidManifest.xml file. and find  android:theme and replcae with android:theme="@style/MYTheme"