# DatePickerDialog displays with two borders

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have a question about DatePickerDialog displaying.

I want to create date picker dialog with "HoloDialog" theme like this:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, reservationDate, 2014, 1, 1);
```

Then I will see this result:
[image: DatePickerDialog with Holo_Dealog]

As you can see, dialog is displayed with "two borders" around.

I want to create the same dialog as displayed here, but with one border around. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please try to illustrate what you exactly mean with '2 borders'? I don't really see borders. Do you mean that you want to see the spinner for the days also and not only month & year?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider. This is about how to change color of a dividers. For your case, if you change dividers colors to background, they be not visible. But you want to change only one divider and I don't know how to do this, but hope that idea in the linked answer may help...

Comment: @Chris I think he means dividers at the top and bottom of "Feb" and "2014"

Comment: @krossovochkin Owh okay, my apologies, i did not understand the question

Comment: @IvanB, do you mean the window borders? The raised inset look?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, I think I found a way. Here, we anonymously subclass `DatePickerDialog` to override `onCreate()` and set a transparent background for the window.

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog,
                                            reservationDate, 2014, 1, 1) {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
};
```

---

You could also do this with a custom theme instead. For example:

```
<style name="HoloDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then pass that in the `DatePickerDialog`'s constructor:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.HoloDialog,
                                            reservationDate, 2014, 1, 1);
```