# How to remove DatePickerDialog background

Tags: java, android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I want to remove the extra background in DatePickerDialog

[image]

This is my code

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(RegisterActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, date,
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DatePickerDialog displays with two borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205161/datepickerdialog-displays-with-two-borders)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the dialog theme like this :

```
<style name="TransparentDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="AlertDialog.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

then apply the theme like this

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(RegisterActivity.this, R.style.TransparentDatePickerDialogTheme, date,
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```