# Datepicker divider color change according to application theme

Tags: java, android, datepicker, customization

I know this question has already been asked and even answered, but I was unable to figure out much from the solution provided. I was trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20291416/1627599) tutorial but I could not figure out exactly what I need to do. I have already downloaded the [Android-DatePicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker) library and changed the image in the `drawable` folder, but after that I could not perform the steps required.

I have this **sample activity**:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePickerDialog;
import net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePicker;

public class SettingsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_portrait);

        Button pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                System.out.println("the selected " + mDay);
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(SettingsActivity.this, new mDateSetListener(), mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dialog.show();

            }

        });
    };

    class mDateSetListener implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // getCalender();
            int mYear = year;
            int mMonth = monthOfYear;
            int mDay = dayOfMonth;
//            v.setText(new StringBuilder()
//                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
//                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("/").append(mDay).append("/")
//                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
//            System.out.println(v.getText().toString());


        }
    }

}
```

What I want to do is that, I want the datepicker to open up when the user clicks on the `pickDate` button. Please tell me the steps to be done after this to achieve the goal. I want the divider color to be `#009945`.

Comment: Can you confirm the fully quantified class name of `DatePickerDialog` you're using?

Comment: @Vikram what do you exactly wanna know? the class name is mDateSetListener according to my activity. If you wanna change the way it is called you can do that.

Comment: No, I mean - are you using `android.app.DatePickerDialog` or `net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePickerDialog`? You can check this in the import statements.

Comment: @Vikram I have edited the source code to include the import statements as well, please check them.

Comment: You said that you changed the drawable in Android-DatePicker library. But you are not using the library here. If you were, the import statement would read `import new.simonvt.datepicker.DatePickerDialog;` instead of `import android.app.DatePickerDialog;`. What I am trying to say is - to get a customized divider, you need the library's implementation of DatePickerDialog, not the framework's.

Comment: @Vikram The library has definition for a number picker and not a date picker, so I was a little confused. Secondly, I also do not understand what to do after adding the library to my project. It will be great if you tell me the steps to be done on my project including the library onwards how to create the datepicker.

Comment: @Vikram actually I am very confused about the implementation of the library in my project. If you want to edit the sample activity feel free to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67223/discussion-between-vikram-and-kittu88).

Comment: @Vikram I have tried the edited class by you. I am receiving The import net.simonvt.datepicker cannot be resolved and DatePickerDialog cannot be resolved to a type errors

Comment: Basically the library package says net.simonvt.numberpicker but we are trying to import net.simonvt.datepicker which does not exist.