# Trouble to change the divider color of DateTime picker?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles, android-datepicker

I am using the DatePicker which extends the DialogFragment.
As UI perspective, how to change the divider color.
Need to change the color of divider which is blue to orange.

please suggest me some way.

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPLht.png)

Comment: Please [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider)

Comment: I tried. Unable to resolve this link,

Comment: okay than please mention in your question whatever you have tried.