# Android: How to remove divider lines in number picker

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, numberpicker

How can I remove divider lines in number picker, I tried setShowDivider to none(seems none doesn't exist) through xml and code noting worked

```
picker.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
```

XML:

```
android:showDividers="none"
```

[image]

Comment: I had used a similar solution to the first one by @AdityaVyas-Lakhan by creating a custom theme.
Use android:color/transparent to access transparent color, if that helps.

Alternatively, you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider/20291416#20291416  and refer the approach used for Datepicker.

Answer (score 27):

Set Theme for Numberpicker

```
<NumberPicker
   ...
   android:theme="@style/DefaultNumberPickerTheme" />
```

style.xml

```
<style name="DefaultNumberPickerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**OR**

```
private void changeDividerColor(NumberPicker picker, int color) {

    java.lang.reflect.Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field pf : pickerFields) {
        if (pf.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {
            pf.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
                pf.set(picker, colorDrawable);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And Set it as

```
changeDividerColor(yournumberpicker, Color.parseColor("#00ffffff"));
```

Comment: why its so difficult to remove/make invisible merely 2 lines in number picker? any other option instead number picker?

Answer (score 7):

Add One of those line in your NumberPicker

XML : `android:selectionDividerHeight="0dp"`

OR

JAVA: `picker.setSelectionDividerHeight(0)`

Comment: `selectionDividerHeight` requires API level 29 and above.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple solution. Calling `picker.setSelectionDividerHeight(0)` could do the trick.

Comment: This attribute is only used in API level 29 and above.

Comment: Then again, these reflection calls are not working anymore in API 29+ so that is a great solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

this code would be better

```
private void changeDividerColor(NumberPicker picker, int color) {
        try {
            Field mField = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider");
            mField.setAccessible(true);
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
            mField.set(picker, colorDrawable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this a greylist reflection call since Android 9? Is that still working (soon)?
See: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces