# I want to make this date picker transparent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, datepicker, transparent

[image]

> **In my data picker XML, I just want these borders to disappear and
>   change the date picker cards color**

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:calendarTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: this might be help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider

Comment: i just added it now