# I want to change the color of these dividers, but I can't find the theme. I use it ` ` ` flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker ` ` `

Tags: line

[image: Image showing the divider]

I want to change the color of these dividers, but I can't find the theme. I use it

```
flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap cupertinoDatePicker with CupertinoTheme. here is an example

```
CupertinoTheme(
    data: CupertinoThemeData(
        textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
            dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22,
                ///more options here
            ),
        ),
     ),
     child: CupertinoDatePicker(
```

Comment: This seems to only change the font, can not change the dividing line

Comment: Here is an example on how to do what you are asking for on android ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider```

Comment: I did. It didn't help me that much. Thank you all the same